# Change seconds to string

Tags: stata

I have these seconds representing the time of completing each lap:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(lap lapruntime)
 1 1386
 2  816
 3 1835
 4 2048
 5  751
 6 2456
 7 1947
 8 1640
 9 2090
10 1372
end
```

Is there a way to change these to an `hours:minutes:seconds` string?

I thought I can do this with the command:

```
format %tcHH:MM:SS lapruntime
```

However, this gives me some strange results.

I would also like to do the same for the difference between each lap run time.

Comment: Clock times in Stata have units milliseconds. This is documented. So e.g. 1386 can only be 1.386 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, there is a community-contributed function for `egen` in this territory, but it is immensely better just to use official offerings and concoct your own code. None of your example times is more than 60 minutes, so getting the minutes one way and the seconds another way leads to a concatenation. A small but needed trick is to use `%02.0f` to ensure that seconds fewer than 10 seconds are shown conventionally.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(lap lapruntime)
 1 1386
 2  816
 3 1835
 4 2048
 5  751
end

egen wanted = elap(lapruntime) 

list 

     +-----------------------------+
     | lap   laprun~e       wanted |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |   1       1386   0:00:23:06 |
  2. |   2        816   0:00:13:36 |
  3. |   3       1835   0:00:30:35 |
  4. |   4       2048   0:00:34:08 |
  5. |   5        751   0:00:12:31 |
     +-----------------------------+

gen minutes = floor(lapruntime/60)
gen seconds = mod(lapruntime, 60)
egen WANTED = concat(minutes seconds), p(:) format(%02.0f)

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | lap   laprun~e       wanted   minutes   seconds   WANTED |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   1       1386   0:00:23:06        23         6    23:06 |
  2. |   2        816   0:00:13:36        13        36    13:36 |
  3. |   3       1835   0:00:30:35        30        35    30:35 |
  4. |   4       2048   0:00:34:08        34         8    34:08 |
  5. |   5        751   0:00:12:31        12        31    12:31 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Those paid by the reciprocal of lines of code can imagine a way to do it in one line as

`strofreal(floor(lapruntime/60)) + ":" + strofreal(mod(lapruntime, 60), "%02.0f")`